# Creating listener of a CustomDialog out of the class in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a listener of a button of a customdialog which extends DialogFragment class and I want to locate the listener of custom buttons out of customdialog fragment class .However when I try to call the view of CustomDialog Fragment then I am getting null exception. What I do is to create an new instance of the customdialog fragment in somewhere else and say

customdialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.custombutton);

but I am getting null.

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

public  final int RES_NONE = -1;
private  TextViewCustomFont dialogTitle, view2, dialogBodyBottom,
        dialogBodyTop;
private  EditTextCustomFont dialogEditText;
private  ButtonCustomFont dialogLeftButton;
private ButtonCustomFont dialogRightButton;
private  Typeface GothamBold, GothamMedium, GothamUltra;
private static  int title1, bodyTop1, bodyBottom1, EditTextHint1,
        leftButton1, rightButton1;
onSubmitListener mListener;

private  Dialog dialog;

interface onSubmitListener {
    void setOnSubmitListener(String arg);
}

public static CustomDialog newInstance(int title, int bodyTop,
        int bodyBottom, int EditTextHint, int leftButton, int rightButton) {

    title1 = title;
    bodyTop1 = bodyTop;
    bodyBottom1 = bodyBottom;
    EditTextHint1 = EditTextHint;
    leftButton1 = leftButton;
    rightButton1 = rightButton;

    CustomDialog frag = new CustomDialog();



    return frag;
}

public ButtonCustomFont getDialogLeftButton() {
    return dialogLeftButton;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    //dialog.show();

    initLayout();

    return dialog;
}

private void initLayout(){
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    setDialogView();
    setCustomDialog();
}

public void setDialogView(){    

    //Create an java object of each dialog view item
    dialogTitle = (TextViewCustomFont) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_title);
    dialogBodyTop = (TextViewCustomFont) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_body_top);
    dialogBodyBottom = (TextViewCustomFont) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_body_bottom);
    dialogEditText = (EditTextCustomFont) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_body_et);
    dialogLeftButton = (ButtonCustomFont) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_body_btn_left);
    dialogRightButton = (ButtonCustomFont)  }
```

---

```
public class LoginSelectionFragment extends Fragment {


public static LoginSelectionFragment newInstance() {

    LoginSelectionFragment fragment = new LoginSelectionFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loginselection,
            container, false);
}
```

I am trying to pull the dialogLeftButton of CustomDialog Fragment and assing a listener on it inside the LoginSelectionFragment.

Here is how it looks like after I added method 2. This a part of LoginSelectionFragment

```
private void TwoButtonTextEditTextDialog(){
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_info_header);
    String body = getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_info_body);
    String body2 = getResources().getString(R.string.hint_newemail);
    String btn1 = getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_uppercase);
    String btn2 = getResources().getString(R.string.ok_alert);

    fragmentDialog = CustomDialog.newInstance(title, body, body2, RES_NONE, btn1, btn2);
    fragmentDialog.setCustomDialogFragmentListener(mDialogClickListener);
    fragmentDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
}

private  CustomDialog.CustomDialogFragmentListener mDialogClickListener = new CustomDialog.CustomDialogFragmentListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void onNegativeClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fragmentDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositiveClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fragmentDialog.dismiss();
    }

};


@Override
public void onNegativeClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPositiveClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you out with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method as `setDialogButtonClickListener(CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener clickListener);` where `CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener` is an inner static interface , that way you could listen to click events of the buttons from anywhere.

An example of this could look as below,

```
   public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

       .....
     public static CustomDialog newInstance(int title, int bodyTop,
        int bodyBottom, int EditTextHint, int leftButton, int rightButton) {

        CustomDialog frag = new CustomDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        ......
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

...
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, this)
                 ....
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (listener != null) {
            switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                listener.onRightButtonClick();
            default:
                listener.onLeftButtonClick();
            }
        }
    }

    ...
    private CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener mClickListener;
    ....

    public void setDialogButtonClickListener(CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener clickListener){
         mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    ...
    public static interface OnButtonClickListener {
       public void onLeftButtonClick();
       public void onRightButtonClick();
    }
    }
```

If you notice from the above sample I posted , I have besides solving your problem of setting the click listener on buttons also have introduced you with the **Factory Design Pattern** on Android , You can see that instead of creating `static` fields for the ***button title and Dialog title*** I've set them in the **Bundle Argument** and then Retrieve them in the Dialogs onCreate() method.

For more Best Practices of Fragment You can take a look [here](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)

**Edit**

Ok , for your help I am providing you a Glimpse of what your LoginSelectionFragment should look like.

```
public class LoginSelectionFragment extends Fragment implements CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener {

    ......// Method 1
    public void showDialog(String title , String message .....) {
         CustomDialog dialog = CustomDialog.getInstance(title , message...);
         dialog.setDialogButtonClickListener(this);
         dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
    }

        public void onLeftButtonClick(){
    ...// do something on left button click of dialog
    }
               public void onRightButtonClick(){
    // do something on right button click of dialog
    ..
    }

    // Method 2
public void showDialog2(String title , String message .....) {
         CustomDialog dialog = CustomDialog.getInstance(title , message...);
         dialog.setDialogButtonClickListener(mDialogClickListener);
         dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
}

private final CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener mDialogClickListener = new CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener() {
  public void onLeftButtonClick(){
        ...// do something on left button click of dialog
        }
                   public void onRightButtonClick(){
        // do something on right button click of dialog
        ..
        }
}
    }
```

Now If you look at **Method 1** , we have given parameters to showDialog() method so that you could ***reuse*** it for showing multiple times with different arguments ie., you could use this approach when you want to show the same dialog with different title , message etc

and in **Method 2** we have provided an anonymous inner class for handling click events you could as many anonymous inner classes as you have different varieties of dialog ie dialog with different UI and different Event listeners in the same activity/fragment.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for this great phrase but I am not able pull the button of this customdialog fragment inside another fragment. This is only  I am looking for. always getting null

Comment: leftBtn.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) getActivity().getApplicationContext());                              ..                                                                  or this:                                                                                                   leftBtn.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);                                                        I am getting this error:                                             ... can not be cast to android.view.View$onClickListener

Comment: @user3152367 I've edited my answer for your help , also in my answer I've elaborated that one should listen to click events of buttons inside DialogFragment in an outside class (or fragment or activity) through an interface , which is good practice called as "Loose Coupling" , you should not pull out any view from a fragment and set a click listener on that , as by pulling out a view you make a "Tight Coupling" which the dialog which is a bad thing, See my answer as to how to implement that, Hope this would have helped you, Cheers!

Comment: Thank you again. Thats what exactly I did yesterday based on what you gave me at the first. But I was thinkinh today what if I have multiple dialogs on same fragment? How would I manage left and right button listener. I can invoke a query based on button's string but I am trying to stay away create queries based on strings for structure. This is my real time project. and I might and probably i will have multiple dialogs on a single fargment in future.

Comment: @user3152367 I've updated my answer , please have a look . I think you want to have different Dialogs with different UI then you could use Method 2 otherwise if you want to show current dialog with different title etc use method 1. Also If you like the answer kindly accept it or upvote it (The best way to express thanks on stack overflow ;)). Cheers!

Comment: That is great example! you got soo close :) sorry I got a little error which is when I implement method 2(this is what exactly I want) I still have to add unimplemented methods which are onLeftButtonClick and onRightButtonClick methods in LoginSelectionFragment. However I will have same methods twice in LoginSelectionFragment. Couldnt find a way around not to add unimplemented methods which are already in mDialogClickListener

Comment: Please see the question I edited. This is how it looks like what I meant

Comment: I got it worked ;) I just removed implement interface and its working fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, (did not test this)
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.input_warning)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

and in your **Activity fragment**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle       savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_a_fragment, container, false);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_WARNING);
    }
```

});}

Comment: No this one wont work because the view you are using to pull Button is belong to Activty Fragment but I want to pull the button of Dialogfragmet inside another Fragment